# Are there any open-source 3D reconstructions of Ancient Rome?

Tags: ancient-rome, technology, reconstruction

I was wondering if there are any open-source i.e. crowdsourced projects generating 3D models of Ancient Rome during the Republic and Imperial Times? I’m especially interested in the area of the Forum Romanum, Capitol and Palatine Hills and Domus aurea/Colosseum across different centuries.

I have found the [RomeReborn project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome_Reborn), which used to be open-source until version 2 (is that 3D model still available anywhere?) but is now a commercial product and with 320 AD as timepoint is of course quite a late version of the capital.

There is [Project Katatexilux](https://www.katatexilux.com/new-gallery-22) that does 3D renderings of various archeological sites and reconstructions in Rome and so they surely must have 3D models but it appears those are also commercial.

There is a [digitized scan](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/massive-scale-model-of-ancient-rome-2f9cb1fbc2eb470686eb8ba596b059cb) of a model by Paul Bigot from the early 20th Century, but again this only has one time-point and the model itself seems quite outdated and not up to date with recent discoveries.

Are there no open source reconstructions maintained primarily by archaeologists/historians for research purposes?

If there is a site that you think is a better fit for the question or if such questions are not allowed on History.SE, do let me know

Comment: If there is a site that you think is a better fit for the question or if such questions are not allowed on History.SE, do let me know